# C# split text when delimiter may be in values

Tags: c#, text, split

I have a text file which is and extract from database. Each line is one record and I'm trying to parse it.

Here is the troublesome part after some anonymisation:

```
"CODE0001"  "Name1  "   14.46   0.05
"CODE0002"  "Name2" 17.37   0.05    
"CODE0003"  "Name3" 22.66   0.05
```

It may have strings or numbers, separated by tabulators. Strings are in brackets. Unfortunately tabulators may happen also in names like "Name1 "
which I learnt by getting some parse errors.

My first code was:

```
string[] articles = File.ReadAllLines(myFile);
char[] separators = { '\t' };

for (int i = 0; i < articles.Length; i++)             
{
    string[] article = articles[i].Split(separators);
    string code = article[0];
    string name = article[1];
    string val1 = article[2];
    string val2 = article[3];
    //do something with these values
 }
```

But if there is a tabulator in some name it goes wrong.

How could I split and parse these lines ignoring tabs in names (surrounded by brackets) and detecting only true delimiters?

Comment: See the linked question, you should use `\t` as delimiter for TextFieldParser